# Instance Variable to store data in cucumber/ruby/watir?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir-webdriver

I am writing some automation tests using ruby/watir/cucumber for a cart. I need to save the item info to be used on the review and confirmation pages. Are instance variables the way to do this? I would imagine some type array of hashes stored in a instance variable since I would need to store the description, quantity ordered, price, and variant. For example:

```
@cartItems = []

apple = {type: 'washington', quantity: 1, price: 0.74}
orange = {type: 'naval', quantity: 2, price: 1.25}
banana = {type: 'cavendish', quantity: 4, price: 0.50, size: 'large'}
@cartItems = push(apple)
@cartItems = push(orange)
@cartItems = push(banana)
```

Then I would read @cartItems to check for those things on the review/confirmation pages? Would be able to add to the @cartItems from any page?

Answer (score 0):

There are several theories about whether this is appropriate or not. Here is [an article](http://chrismdp.com/2012/11/storing-state-in-your-steps/) which discusses the pros and con.

Here is the outline.

> - It leads to more readable steps
> - We lose referential transparency for our steps
> - Is it worth it?
>
>   - We’re relying on state anyway
>   - I’m not a big fan of step reuse.
> - Use member variables with care

Comment: Thanks for the link to the article. I am definitely trying to limit the instance variables I use. Perhaps putting them in a helper module would work best.

Answer (score 0):

To get truly robust with this you should probably start using the "Test Data Builder" design pattern. This pattern will allow you to create and store large data structures to be used in your tests. See the TestFactory gem's documentation for a description of one way to code this pattern: https://github.com/rSmart/TestFactory